# Android Streaming Video - Need Aspect Ratio

Tags: android, video-streaming, media-player

I am using the Android MediaPlayer demo for Video.  I have streaming video 640x480.  I simply want the video to be as large as it can be (in whatever device orientation) while keeping aspect ratio.  I can't get it to do this. It simply stretches across the entire screen. My SurfaceView in the layout doesn't maintain aspect ratio in either "fill_parent" or "wrap_content".  When I check (and change the surface size in code, it seems to ignore any changes.  And what is weird is I am told in this code that my video size is : 176 x 144.

```
public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) 
{
    Log.v(TAG, "onVideoSizeChanged called");
    Log.v(TAG, "Surface Width: " + width + " Surface Height: " + height);
    if (width == 0 || height == 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "invalid video width(" + width + ") or height(" + height + ")");
        return;
    }
    mIsVideoSizeKnown = true;
    mVideoWidth = width;
    mVideoHeight = height;

    mVideoWidth = mp.getVideoWidth();
    mVideoHeight = mp.getVideoHeight();
    Log.v(TAG, "Surface Width: " + mVideoWidth + " Surface Height: " + mVideoHeight);
    if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed && mIsVideoSizeKnown) {
        startVideoPlayback();
    }
}
```

This is where I try and change the size:

```
private void startVideoPlayback() {
    Log.v(TAG, "startVideoPlayback");
    holder.setFixedSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);
    mMediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

try to use setLayoutParams() in OnPrepared()

```
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
   ...
   mSurfaceView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(vWidth, vHeight));
   ...
};
```